# Unity y C#. Cambiar FontSize de un texto JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Dentro del `OnGUI()` tengo:

```
GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(75, 500, 900, 200));
```

dentro, cojo el JSON y muestro su contenido:

```
GUILayout.Label(json[0][0][textInComp][0].Value, GUI.skin.textArea);
```

Y finalizo:

```
GUILayout.EndArea();
```

Alguien sabe cómo cambiar el **tamaño del texto** de dentro del *Label*? El cuál cojo del JSON.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un nuevo `GUIStyle` para ese texto en concreto y hacer lo siguiente:

```
private GUIStyle myStyle;

private void Start()
{
    myStyle = new GUIStyle();
    myStyle.fontSize = 20; // Aquí pones el tamaño de fuente deseado
}

private void OnGUI()
{
    GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(75, 500, 900, 200));
    // Le pasas el nuevo estilo como argumento
    GUILayout.Label(json[0][0][textInComp][0].Value, myStyle);
    GUILayout.EndArea();
}
```